# 「失敗、エラーの危険と裏腹のものです。」の意味

Tags: meaning

早稲田大学高等学院中学部の[学院長からの挨拶](https://www.waseda.jp/school/jhs/about/message/)（上から3番目の段落）にある文章ですが、意味がよく分かりません。

> 学校は皆さんの挑戦をサポートしていきます。一つは、皆さんの未知なる問題への挑戦を、伝統的な早稲田の学風－自由－がサポートします。これは、「寛容」と言い換えても良いでしょう。 **答えの未だ明らかでない問題への挑戦は、リスクを伴うものです。失敗、エラーの危険と裏腹のものです。失敗が許されない環境では、挑戦も許されません。** リスク・テイクする自覚が、責任意識も自律の精神も生み出します。私たちは、自由の学風に裏打ちされた寛容をもって、皆さんの挑戦をサポートします。そして、エラーから学んでより大きな挑戦に進む、タフに挑戦し続ける皆さんを応援します。

「答えの未だ明らかでない問題への挑戦は、リスクを伴うものです。」の部分は分かりやすいですが、挑戦にはリスクがあるものだというなら、それは失敗するかもしれないからではないでしょうか？しかし、「 **〔そのリスクは〕** 失敗、エラーの危険と裏腹 **〔正反対〕** のもの」という理解が正しいとしても、意味が分かりません。それとも、挑戦自体は失敗の危険の正反対という意味でしょうか？

まだ見えていない解釈が正しいでしょうか？教えてください！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

辞書には 「裏腹」の意味としてこう書いてあります。

> １ 背と腹。また、裏と表。
>
> ２ 背中合わせ。隣り合わせの関係であること。「死と裏腹の危険な仕事」
>
> ３ 相反していること。また、そのさま。逆さま。反対。あべこべ。「気持ちと裏腹な言葉」

この文章での「裏腹」の意味は、2番です。だから、「 〔答えの未だ明らかでない問題への挑戦は、〕 失敗、エラーの危険と裏腹 〔背中合わせ〕 のものです。」と言う意味です。